# Jasper Server : Название файла при экспорте

Tags: jasperreports, jasperstudio

При экспорте отчета в любом формате с  jasperserver  отчет называется по "Resource ID".
Как задать название отчета при экспорте (желательно на кириллице) не трогая "Resource ID"?